# Program can't find Boost Graph installed in Docker

Tags: c++, docker, boost, gitlab-ci

I am using dockers to store the dependencies of my c++ program to use when doing CI testing with gitlab CI. I first build a base docker which contains all of the program dependencies (lets call it `DOCKER_A`):

```
FROM gcc:5

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/optimization
WORKDIR /usr/optimization

#COPY . /usr/optimization

RUN apt-get update && \
 apt-get upgrade -y && \
 apt-get install -y build-essential && \
 apt-get install -y openssh-client && \
 apt-get install -y python3 && \
 apt-get install -y python3-pip && \
 pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
 pip3 install virtualenv
RUN wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.7/cmake-3.7.2.tar.gz && \
 tar xf cmake-3.7.2.tar.gz && \
 cd cmake-3.7.2/ && \
 ./configure && \
 make && \
 make install && \
 export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH && \
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && \
 cd ..
RUN wget -O boost_1_64_0.tar.gz http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.64.0/boost_1_64_0.tar.gz/download && \
 tar xzvf boost_1_64_0.tar.gz && \
 cd boost_1_64_0 && \
 ./bootstrap.sh --exec-prefix=/usr/local --with-python=python3 && \
 ./b2 threading=multi && \
 ./b2 install threading=multi && \
 cd .. && \
 rm boost_1_64_0.tar.gz && \
 rm -r boost_1_64_0 && \
 ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python3.so
```

This docker doesn't change. Then every time I push to gitlab, I build another docker, starting from `DOCKER_A`:

```
FROM DOCKER_A

ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY

WORKDIR /usr/optimization
COPY . /usr/optimization

RUN chmod +x ADD_KEY.sh
RUN ./ADD_KEY.sh "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"

RUN mkdir build && \
 cd build && \
 cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=on .. && \
 make && \
 cd ..
```

This builds the code from the new commit (up to this point everything works as expected).

Next, in my YAML file for gitlab CI, I run my tests, which consist of calling the executable files generated by my build process.

```
before_script:
  - docker info
  - docker login -u user -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN docker.registry.url

after_script:
  - echo "After script section"
  - echo "For example you might do some cleanup here"

buildRelease:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Do your build here"
    - docker login -u user -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN docker.registry.url
    - docker build --pull -i $CONTAINER_IMAGE_PUSH --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE_PUSH

testDispatch:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Do a test here"
    - echo "For example run a test suite"
    - docker run -t $CONTAINER_IMAGE_PULL ./bin/dispatch

testState:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker run -t $CONTAINER_IMAGE_PULL ./bin/state-test

testAlgorithm:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker run -t $CONTAINER_IMAGE_PULL ./bin/algorithm-test

testSystem:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker run -t $CONTAINER_IMAGE_PULL ./bin/system-test
```

Each of these the tests in `stage test` fails, all giving the same error. Here is an example of the output:

```
$ docker run -t $CONTAINER_IMAGE_PULL ./bin/algorithm-test

./bin/algorithm-test: error while loading shared libraries:
libboost_graph.so.1.64.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I don't understand why my binary cannot find libboost graph, as it is installed in the first docker container, which I am inheriting from.

Any help that could be provided would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you verify that libboost_graph.so is in your $LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

Comment: That was my problem -- I didn't realize that my `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` command wouldn't persist  -- thanks.

Comment: You may consider running the job inside the container you have built instead of having the job run the container.